# How to set the parameters for the sql query with the union operator while using getJdbcTemplate.query(sql,new Object[],rowmapper))?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, union, jdbctemplate

I Have the query similar to this one :

sql :

```
select count("A"),"B","C" from schema."xxx" where  "TIME"<? and "TIME">=? AND "C"='mmn' group by "B","C" 
union  
select count("A"),"B","C" from schema."xxx" where  "TIME"<? and "TIME">=? AND "C"='nno' group by "B","C" order by "C"
```

and I am using a

```
getJdbctemplate.query(sql,new Object[startTime,EndTime],Rowmapper)
```

I am not sure if this is not the correct way to pass the arguments cause when I try to do this it is erroring out wrt an incorrect number of parameters passed.

Comment: show the full stacktrace

Comment: SOF says its too long.. Also I am new to this place how do it put it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace 4 `?` placholders

```
 getJdbctemplate.query(sql,new Object[startTime,EndTime , startTime,EndTime ],Rowmapper)
```

Also it seems that you should start with endDate

If you used `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` you could use 2 placeholders as `:startDate` and `:endDate`

Comment: Thanks for the response!, This I am doing in the old code which was written by someone else and if I change it to NamedParameterJdbcTemplate I would need to change for all the other methods as well, also if i have it exclusively for this one then there will be 2 instances of jdbc templates. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Also i have tried doing this getJdbctemplate.query(sql,new Object[startTime,EndTime , startTime,EndTime ],Rowmapper)  its still the same result